# Is a C implementation of the C++ STL technically infeasible?

Tags: c, stl

There are a few questions on here asking whether such a thing exists, usually with answers promoting void pointers.

I'd like the data structures and algorithms to be strongly typed. I think this is feasible, though the implementation would be lengthy!

The plan is to parameterise the data structures, iterators and algorithms by type name, performing name mangling with the C preprocessor. It'll lean hard on the #include directive to write out the permutations. Finally, wrap the result in a friendly polymorphic interface to hide the mangled names (C11 _Generic based).

The ideal answer would be either "sure, that'll work" or "nope, C can't do X". I'm essentially looking for guidence on whether this looks like a fool's errand. Thank you

Comment: So what you want to do is basically a reimplementation of C++? And for your information, C++ started out as a C preprocessor which did most of what you want to do.

Comment: I could be very wrong, but I feel that it would be difficult to find a platform that supported C11 that did not also already support C++.

Comment: Is this asking for *the* STL, or *a* type-safe container library? The answer is trivial either way: 1) no, `_Generic` isn't anywhere near powerful enough to replace even a fraction of what templates can do; 2) yes, `_Generic` is more than powerful enough to be useful and safe.

Comment: I was looking for the functionality of the STL without the C++ dependency, i.e. data structures and algorithms based on programmer defined types. Doing this in C is feasible, if verbose. _Generic is an interface, not the code generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1992 is calling and want their technology back.

The first C++ compilers actually converted C++ into C, so yes it can be done, but you need to look a bit deeper into why you want to do it and whether it's worthwhile.

Comment: I'm not sure cfront could handle the complexity of modern templates, but the general sentiment makes sense. "Just write a compiler" is a solution - a code generator is evidently capable of writing anything. Whether macros comprise a sufficient generator is less clear. "Why" is probably impossible to answer without provoking rage from some C++ users, so lets just say "for fun". Thanks